# Better admin security

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I try to make my firs CMS and I have querstion about security. I right now have seperated admin area and public area. My admin area is in folder "admin" and my public area is in folder "public". Both folders are in my folder "cms". In both maps is for example: file called "index.php". And content is the same but in admin's index.php  have few more features for example: in admin's navigation i have logout and settings options. So would be better if I from this two folders make one called "public" and both "index.php" connect together into one file and control it with $_SESSION to add additional features to navigation?
Example: If is admin logged in then with session will show settings and logout features to navigation. When is user logged out he won't see settings and logout featuers in navigation because it will only show when user has set session.
So, is better and more secure to have seperated admin and public folder or is the same if I put everything in one file?

Comment: It doesn't make it more secure to have it separate, even with a random folder name on the admin part this is still security by obscurity, which isn't worth much. It could make sense to split the views if they are very different, but if it's only a link here and there it doesn't sound like it will clutter up the normal view files too much.

Comment: Your question seems more about usability vs. security. Separating it makes sense if that really avoids administrative code in the main application. Reducing complexity does occassionally aid security. A separate folder is also easier to guard with two factor authorization (e.g. client-side ssl certification in conjunction to a login form).

Answer (score 0):

In my cms, I use the same page for public, users, and admins.

The different is in showing some extra functionality based on the group.

i.e. for normal visitors (public) users do not see except the published contents.  but if a visitor signed in to his account, then he will see some extra peaces here and there (i.e. profile img, personal info, change email/password).  on the other hand, the admin has his own extras as well, such as control users, messages, and etc.

off course some times there are a totally new things that is not shared between these 3 levels of privileges.  in this case, I create a separate page to them...

The most important things here is to check the user group and based on that group you display this part and hide that part.

something like

```
if user group == 1 // an admin
{
display admin_sidebar.php
}
elseif user group == 2 // a member
{
display member_profile.php link
}
```

Also off course you need to use sessions to handle this group for you just after the user logged in to your website.

hope that helps...